# Is there a way to have docpad use markdown and eco with the extension .eco.md?

Tags: docpad

Since docpad allows you to use multiple plugin processors on a file, I would like to be able to use both markdown and eco but also be able to have the final extension be `.md`.

1. `foo.html.md.eco` works - both plugins run and the output is correct
2. `foo.html.eco.md` does not work - neither plugin runs

Version 2 is superior since it has the final extension of `.md` which my operating system and text editors would then recognize as a markdown and open the right app and highlighting mode.

Is there anyway to configure or fix this so that version 2 would work?

Comment: After looking at the two plugins, I believe I understand why this doesn't work. The marked plugin is limiting its use to outExtension null or html, which can be changed, however the showstopper is that marked will escape the `<%` during processing such that eco will not see the tags. So given that new information, I will have to live with .md.eco

Comment: Yeah... Have you seen the text plugin: http://docpad.org/p/text - it allows you to render a little bit of whatever here, and a little bit of whatever there. Perhaps it can help?

Comment: Thanks I will check that out, it could prove very useful. I am enjoying using docpad thus far, so these extra plugins are just icing on the cake.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments posted, there are a few things that went on.

`foo.html.eco.md` doesn't work as the marked plugin must render to the html extension, which the eco extension is not. Doing `foo.html.eco.html.md` should work.

However doing this render will escape the `<%` tags so eco doesn't see them, so this is not viable if you want to render eco.

An alternative approach is to use the [text plugin](http://docpad.org/p/text) which allows you to render things via elements instead of files and extensions. E.g.

```
<t render="markdown">do **this**</t>
<t render="eco">do <%- 'this'.toUpperCase() %></t>
```